# Keyword 'Dictionary Should Contain Item' failed by the mismatch of types

Tags: python, robotframework

## Problem:

**I'm getting int type from JSON, str type from manually-created dictionary.**
Local running passed case, but running on jenkins failed it:
*Value of dictionary key 'columns' does not match: 2 (integer) != 2 (string)*
[image]

## Details:

I'm comparing 2 dictionaries, first generated by json parser, second i manually create,
Simple order of steps here are - download ZIP, unarchive, parse JSON as DICT, compare values with DICT

How i parse JSON:
`

```
def json_loads(json_str):
    dict_data = json.loads(json_str)
    return dict_data
```

`

How compare:
`

```
Compare Widget's Params As Dictionaries
    [Arguments]  &{param}
    <...>

IF  'columns' in &{param}
...    Dictionary Should Contain Item    ${param.result}   columns    ${param.columns}
```

`

.robot code:

```
&{param2}    Create Dictionary    title=${name_w2}    description=Description ${rndString}
...    font_color=f5aef5    back_color=303030    columns=2

Open Test Form Page
${file}    Export All Widgets
${path}    Normalize Path    ${DOWNLOAD_PATH}/results/Archive_export_${rndString}
Extract Files From Zip    ${file}    ${DOWNLOAD_PATH}/results/Archive_export_${rndString}
Remove File    ${file}
Find Widget An Check Params From File JSON    file=widget_data.json    &{param2}
```

Keyword:

```
Find Widget An Check Params From File JSON
[Arguments]  &{param}
${file}    Get File    ${param.file}
@{results}    JSON Loads    ${file}
${length}    Get Length    ${results}
${result}    Set Variable    ${EMPTY}
FOR  ${i}  IN RANGE  0  ${length}
    IF    '${results}[${i}][name]'=='${param.title}'
        ${result}    Set Variable    ${results}[${i}]
        BREAK
    END
END
Should Not Be Empty    ${result}    Can't find widget with title '${param.title}' in JSON
Compare Widget's Params As Dictionaries    result=${result}    &{param}
```

JSON:

```
[{"id":null,"uniqueKey":"KYvKkaaa-oleg-4709-9f1a-a5f3c491634f","name":"AT Imported Widget KYvKkaaa1","description":null,"order":2,"type":"xip","imageId":null,"bgColor":null,"fontColor":null,"widgetUrls":[],"roles":["Order/Service Admin","ACA Admin"],"columns":1,"systemWidget":false},{"id":null,"uniqueKey":"KYvKkaaa-oleg-4f6c-aaac-b0916038ba6c","name":"AT Imported Widget KYvKkaaa2","description":"Description KYvKkaaa","order":3,"type":"xip","imageId":61,"bgColor":"000000","fontColor":"ffffff","widgetUrls":[{"id":null,"uniqueKey":"KYvKkaaa-oleg-4215-a662-93b8cc99e59a","name":"Name1","url":"https://any.net/d/DC4aoLn4z/template_flowone_orders_requests?orgId=1&from=1663856169916&to=1663856169916&theme=dark&viewPanel=16?1"},{"id":null,"uniqueKey":"KYvKkaaa-oleg-4b25-973a-048788c99399","name":"Name2","url":"https://any.net/d/DC4aoLn4z/template_flowone_orders_requests?orgId=1&from=1663856169916&to=1663856169916&theme=dark&viewPanel=16?2"},{"id":null,"uniqueKey":"KYvKkaaa-oleg-4b26-973a-048788c99399","name":"Name3","url":"https://any.net/d/DC4aoLn4z/template_flowone_orders_requests?orgId=1&from=1663856169916&to=1663856169916&theme=dark&viewPanel=16?3"}],"roles":["Order/Service Admin","ACA Admin"],"columns":2,"systemWidget":false}]
```

## Questions:

1. Why it's happening only on Jenkins?
2. How to avoid this problem - in my case it should pass, bcs symbol 2 in both ways.

Comment: Can you please paste your dictionary value used and parsed

Comment: What's the question? How to catch the exception and say they don't match? We could use a working reproduction.

Comment: Guys, have updated description, add more info, questions.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for question 2:
Robot Framework treats variable values as strings so try fixing your dictionary to look like below. Then the variables are integers.

```
&{param2}    Create Dictionary    title=${name_w2}    description=Description ${rndString}
...    font_color=f5aef5    back_color=${303030}    columns=${2}
```

Comment: Thanks. Typing into dictionary help, local and jenkins running passed. Now left just fist question why it's happened on Jenkins (maybe there are some configuration of RF).